# Trouble with object-based QSignalMapper

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots, qsignalmapper

I am trying to set up a signal-slot arrangement in PyQt where the signal transmits a lot of information. I want to use a `QObject` as a carrier by setting the various information I want to transmit as attributes of the `QObject`. In theory, this should work - there is a `QSignalMapper.setMapping()` overload which takes a sender and a `QObject` as arguments.

Here's the reduced code:

```
self.mapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()
self.timeline.finished.connect(self.mapper.map)
carrier = QtCore.QObject()
carrier.contents = (item1, item2)
self.mapper.setMapping(self.timeline, carrier)
self.portalMapper.mapped.connect(self.report)

def report(self, carrierObject):
    print 'Triggered'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've traced the problem to the `setMapping` function by process of elimination.

This same scheme will work just fine if I switch out the `QObject` with an `int`. It also doesn't have anything to do with the attributes I added to the `QObject` - using a fresh-out-of-the-box `QObject` causes the same issue.

It seems like there is something going on here with this *specific* overload of the `setMapping` function. Any ideas about what the issue is here?

Comment: There's no value in using `QSignalMapper`. Just define a custom signal and send the data directly.

Comment: I'm unsure how to do that, @ekhumoro ... The signal my code is waiting for is the Qt-standard `QTimeline.finished`, and has to be, since I'm waiting for a timer to conclude before proceeding with the next step. I could connect the `finished()` signal to a function which in turn sends a custom signal... but wouldn't that just be recapitulating the purpose of the a QSignalMapper, to receive a signal and send a new signal with a new argument?

Comment: Sure - but it does it a lot more simply. Does your code really need to send a signal at all, though? In your example, there is only one consumer of the signal (`self`), so emitting a signal appears to be completely redundant. All you're doing is sending a pointer to an object, not the data itself (i.e. nothing is ever copied). You might as well keep a reference to the data itself as an attribute of `self`, and then access that directly in a slot connected to the `finished` signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ekhumoro's suggestion to skip the QSignalMapper approach entirely and just create a custom signal. Worked like a charm.